# Give Out Wordpress post_content?

Tags: wordpress, posts

My problem is that I want give out `post_content`, but the output is with raw shortcodes and HTML.

I need an output with the correct translating.

A link should be a link and not a href, but only normal text with links.

When a media file is inside the post, I want to ignore this.

I don't want a big preview for my posts - only a simple one.

My output code:

```
$html .= '<p>'.string_limit_words($numpost->post_content, 20).'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `$numpost->post_content` through the `the_content` filter, like so:

`apply_filters( 'the_content', $numpost->post_content )`

Further reading: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/